# magento 2 getDestCity() method returns nothing in collectRates() method

Tags: magento2

I try to `getDestCity()` in checkout page in magento 2.1.2 .

I check M`agento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request` method to get

***$request->getDestCity();***

it's return null for every shipping method i check magento default Tablerate shipping method.

Answer (score 1):

It's a known issue with Magento - see issue report [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3789). Currently it looks like the fix is scheduled for release in 2.1.8 and 2.2.0.